# Узнать, какая связь установлена между двумя XElement

Tags: c#, xml

Подскажите, как оптимально узнать, кем для другу приходятся 2 XElement'а:

Есть между ними отношения родитель-ребенок, либо они вообще для друг друга никтому.

Comment: `e1.AncestorsAndSelf().Contains(e2)`?

Comment: Ну или циклом, от `e1` вверх по `.Parent`.

Comment: Братья/сестры считаются?

Comment: @defaultlocale не, но можно для полного решения и их включить, если ты готовишь ответ.

Comment: Не готовлю, просто уточнил. Если нет, то вариант VladD вверху должен подойти.